# Adding time that totals more than 24 hrs in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add time from several rows, and when they add up to more than hours I do not get correct results I am looking for. Would like to script `TotalTime` to allow more than 24 in HH. Does not have to be a datetime datatype.

`StartTime` and `FinishTime` are varchar(8) data types.

here is code and output where `TotalTime` is less than 24 hours and correct results

```
SELECT Codes = (DeptCode + '-' +  OpCode)
,TotalTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)),0)) 
,Units = SUM(Units)
,UPH = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
,'Goal%' = (convert(varchar,cast((isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60)/5101*100 as decimal(10,0))) + '%') 
FROM PTW.dbo.TimeLog 
WHERE DeptCode = 'HP' AND OpCode = 'FC'
GROUP BY DeptCode, OpCode
```

Results are correct

```
Codes   TotalTime   Units   UPH   Goal%
HP-FC   12:37:00    47200   3741    73%
```

Here is actual breakdown to prove

```
ID#     Codes   TotalTime   Units   UPH     Goal%   AssociateName
---     -----   ---------   -----   ---     -----   -------------
2409193 HP-FC   00:21:00    2161    6174    121%    NAME
2507191 HP-FC   00:23:00    2000    5217    102%    NAME
90290   HP-FC   00:20:00    1704    5112    100%    NAME
31676   HP-FC   02:35:00    11234   4349    85%     NAME
2372437 HP-FC   01:50:00    7884    4300    84%     NAME
2378337 HP-FC   07:08:00    22217   3115    61%     NAME
```

So when I attempt this on a larger table with more rows of data this is what I get. Out put will show `TotalTime` as an incorrect time.

```
SELECT Codes = (DeptCode + '-' +  OpCode)
,TotalTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)),0))     
,Units = SUM(Units)
,UPH = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
,'Goal%' = (convert(varchar,cast((isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60)/1552*100 as decimal(10,0))) + '%') 
FROM PTW.dbo.TimeLog
WHERE DeptCode = 'HS' AND OpCode = 'HY'
GROUP BY DeptCode, OpCode
```

Results from query are below. This can not be true time.

```
Codes   TotalTime   Units   UPH     Goal%
HS-HY   14:07:00    69204   1114    72%
```

Breakdown to show you that `TotalTime` should be more than 14:07:00

```
ID#     Codes   TotalTime   Units   UPH     Goal%   AssociateName
---     -----   ---------   -----   ---     -----   -------------
2377    HS-HY   11:25:00    20891   1830    118%    NAME
3476    HS-HY   04:50:00    6978    1444    93%     NAME
43864   HS-HY   12:20:00    17628   1429    92%     NAME
2372127 HS-HY   03:20:00    4748    1424    92%     NAME
2372129 HS-HY   07:00:00    9158    1308    84%     NAME
2422946 HS-HY   00:47:00    949     1211    78%     NAME
21437   HS-HY   06:02:00    6530    1082    70%     NAME
2372090 HS-HY   11:00:00    2322    211     14%     NAME
63448   HS-HY   03:43:00    0       0       0%      NAME
2372061 HS-HY   01:40:00    0       0       0%      NAME
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For intervals that may exceed 24 hours you will need to concatenate a set of expressions that calculate each piece like so:

```
select 
    Codes     = (DeptCode + '-' + OpCode)
  , TotalTime = right('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)) / 3600 )),2) + ':' 
              + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)) / 60) % 60 ),2) + ':' 
              + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)) % 60 )),2)
  , Units     = sum(Units)
  , UPH       = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute, StartTime, FinishTime)) * 1.0, 0), 0.0) * 60 as decimal(10, 0))
  , [Goal%]   = (convert(varchar, cast((isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute, StartTime, FinishTime)) * 1.0, 0), 0.0) * 60) / 5101 * 100 as decimal(10, 0))) + '%')
from ptw.dbo.TimeLog
where DeptCode = 'HP'
  and OpCode = 'FC'
group by 
    DeptCode
  , OpCode
```

---

Also, you should not use string literals for aliases, for aliases that do not conform to the rules for regular identifiers, enclose them in square brackets instead of single quotes.

- [Database Identifiers - docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that the time datatype isn't big enough to hold values greater than 24 hours.

You will need to create other types of variables to keep track of hours, minutes, seconds, etc. - as accurately as you need to.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql

Comment: do you have an test script I can try?

Comment: @DRUIDRUID It looks like you accepted another answer, so I assume you're all set at this point.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are converting the sum to a `time` datatype, which means "the time portion of a datetime".  So that will never show a total of more than 24, because even in military time, there is no such thing as 25 o'clock.

To get your correct total, one way is to build a `varchar` datatype instead of a `time` type.  You will need to construct the varchar string by taking your seconds and dividing by 60 and 60*60 to generate the minute and hour portions.

Comment: Tab, can you propose a script I can test?